# Не работают CSS модули

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Почему то у меня не работают добавление классов.

Я их подключаю как `module.css`. Фаил `jsx` и `profile.module.css` находятся в одной директории.

Код:

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './profile.modele.css';
const Profile = () => {
  return (
      <div className={s.content}>
          <img className={s.backgrownd} src='https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png' alt='Упс'></img>
          <img className={s.ava} src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg' alt='Упс'></img>
        <h2>Идиот</h2>
        <div>Просто описание</div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в названии, поправьте `modele` на `module`:

```
import React from "react"
import s from "./profile.module.css"

const Profile = () => {
  return (
      <div className={s.content}>
          <img className={s.backgrownd} src="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png" alt="Упс"></img>
          <img className={s.ava} src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" alt="Упс"></img>
        <h2>Идиот</h2>
        <div>Просто описание</div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

Так же стоит проверить правильность путей и то может ли Ваш сборщик правильно обрабатывать CSS модули.

Comment: Спасибо огромное